# Core Data NSArrayController Doesn't Save or Undo Programmatic Elements

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, core-data

I have a document-based Cocoa application in OS X with a Core Data backed `NSArrayController` bound to the columns of an `NSTableView` and "Add" and "Remove" buttons.

This all works fine, objects added and modified using these bindings get added to the undo stack and save to files as expected.

However when I `.addObject()` programmatically, it is reflected in the table (and therefore, it would seem, the `NSManagedObjectContext`), but not added to the undo stack, or saved to files.

What am I missing? Some setting in my `NSArrayController`? Or some other call after `.addObject()`?

I have heard "Handles Content As Compound Value" mentioned in relation to similar problems, but this seems to be when using the Content Array binding, which I am not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `.addObject()` on the array that your NSArrayController is managing? That won't work because you are bypassing Core Data.

To insert programmatically, use `insertNewObjectForEntityForName(inManagedObjectContext)`. Then the array controller will see the change. Or call `add()` on your array controller, which is what your Add button is doing. But `insertNewObjectForEntityForName()` is a better choice, because it will work independent of whether you have an active NSDocument.

Comment: I'm calling `.addObject( instanceOfNSManagedObject )` on my `NSArrayController`. `add()` works as expected, but of course creates a default initialised object.

Comment: Ahh, it works with `.add()` or `.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(…)`, then setting the object parameters afterwards, thank you. Though I still think I must have something set up wrong if `.addObject(…)` is failing.

Comment: addObject() on the array will fail. What object are you adding? An NSManagedObject you created with alloc/init? Core Data is different. You must tell the MOC to create the object. I believe your setup is correct but that your insertion code is wrong. Can we see that?

Comment: It's on the `NSArrayController` that I'm calling `.addObject(…)` though, not an array.

Comment: My code is like: `let foo = NSManagedObjectSubclass(entity: pointEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil); barArrayController.addObject( foo )`

Comment: If I set the `NSManagedObjectContext` with `insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` it works. But also adds the object in the process. I figure there must be a way of creating the object, then adding it later. Like in ActiveRecord. Otherwise, what's `.addObject(…)` for?

Comment: I just took a close look at NSArrayController's documentation. `add:` says it creates and adds an object. `addObject:` merely adds. I expect that `.addObject()` is for cases where the NSArrayController is managing a regular NSArray instead of one that's owned by Core Data. Your insertIntoManagedObjectContext should, I believe, have a non-nil parameter for the insertIntoManagedObjectContext parameter (probably self.document.managedObjectContext).